# Form input and submit button not aligned

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple form containing an input and a submit button. I use bootstrap for responsiveness. When the screen size is `md` I expect the input field to be aligned with the input as the `label` is set to `col-md-2`, the input to `col-md-10` and the submit to `col-md-10` with an offset of `col-md-offset-2`. The alignment does not happen the way I expected it to, any ideas why this is happening?

**Update**

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Label</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="height: 50px;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m2rcxdx2/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you have two form-groups encasing your submit button which shoves it off from the left just a hair.

http://jsfiddle.net/m2rcxdx2/4/

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-2 control-label">Label</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="name">
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Done</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Label</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" name="name" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="height: 50px;">
        <div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f4u6g0zh/

Comment: I don't think that's the case, here is what happens when I switch: http://jsfiddle.net/m2rcxdx2/2/ . Posted the code